# How to make an IFRAME stretch all the vertical space inside a table cell?

Tags: html, firefox, iframe, height, stretch

I have a table cell whose width is fixed at 180 pixels and height is variable. I want to display an IFRAME inside it.

My code is as below:

```
<iframe
    src="mypage.html"
    width="180px"
    height="100%"
    frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

It works in Google Chrome 13.0.782.220 without any problem.

But in Mozilla Firefox 6.0.2, the height of the IFRAME does not cover the entire cell. Its height is not enough to display all of its contents, so vertical scroll bar appears.

I want to make the IFRAME stretch inside the table cell in Mozilla Firefox just like it does in Google Chrome. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible in HTML. I had this same problem once. Try changing your design.

Answer (score 0):

Per spec, if the height of your table cell is `auto` then the height of that iframe is also `auto`...  If Gecko supported cells being absolute containing blocks you could do this with absolute positioning and 0 offsets, but that won't work either, unfortunately.